# Any tuned E-bike with good support at high cadence high speed?

Tags: electric-bike

We bought a Cannondale Kinneto 2013 for my girlfriend and I also mounted a tuning kit that removes the 25km/h limit. I am a well trained cyclist and the goal would be to "accelerate" my girlfriend to reach around 32-33km/h on the flat. We previously tried other tuned e-mtbs and now the conclusion is the same for a wide range of Bosch motors (Gen1, Acive Line (gen2) and Performance CX (gen3)):

The lower the cadence the higher the support the motor provides. Meaning that with the tuning I can easily ride at 37 km/h with 90-95rpm on a flat part, but even in turbo mode the displayed (and felt) support is very low (10-15%). At this speed if I start shifting to smaller gears then after each shift I can feel and see a jump in the support and as a result I can reach 40km/h with the same effort but with lower cadence. It is very annoying, because the rider of such a bike is then more motivated to cycle at low rpms that is not the most beneficial to build up good cardio and muscle system for biking.

Now I am pretty sure the control algorithm in these Bosch motors are tuned to put out greater torque and power at lower rpms. On the Intuvia display I can also see the rate of support that in my opinion should be between 0 and 250% for our gen1 classic line+ device. At an acceleration with low cadence this shows a maximum support in turbo mode, therefore I think it works correctly. Of course if I push the pedal with already 200-300W then definitely the motor is going to be restricted to 80-120% to stay under the 250W limit. Summary: the defined support levels of the different assistance modes are not meant to be constant but they vary dynamically with the cadence.

What I would like to achieve: find an e-bike for my girlfriend that can give good support even at 40km/h because sometimes we have a strong tailwind. Similarly on downhill parts I can easily reach 50km/h but according to her she hit a wall at 40-45km/h (of course this can come from the max supported cadence of the gen1 motor (105rpm)).

So please share any experience with me about tuned ebikes and how they operate at higher speed with 90-95 rpm. I am especially interested in electric road bikes because they usually have Shimano or Yamaha system and we have never tried them before.

Comment: I’ve tried reading this 3 times and I’m not sure what the question is. If you’re after cardio and with the speeds you have mentioned why bother with the motorised part? 30-35km/h on a flat is well capable on a normal road bike.

Comment: So, my question is if there is any better e-bike system for my current goals than the one from Bosch. My girlfriend is not a trained cyclist, actually she is more of a sprinter. If we want to train together then I need a solution which could support until 40km/h at higher cadence. Last time 32km/h in front wind was not an issue for her, but 40km/h in tail wind did not work. As the e-bike system developer brands totally hide the algorithm behind the real level of assistance I would need experience from other bikers with non-Bosch motor.

Comment: You can get a motorbike, or electric motorbike. Seriously, this is not just a sarcastic remark, e-bikes are simply not built for this kind of usage and any  accident with  illegal modifications can have very unpleasant consequences. The assist in ebikes is mainly to get you over hills in reasonable time and effort, not to go fast on flats.

Comment: would you hire the world-expert physician in doping to help your girlfriend to achieve higher speed on a flat to get on par with you? No? why not? maybe because he would perform some practice that may harm, physically and legally, your girlfriend? now think about you tuning an e-bike ... how different is that? Ok, it is cheaper.

Comment: Have you considered  an untrained cyclist riding at 50km/h might not be the wisest thing to encourage?

Comment: Are you aware that you're pretty recklessly putting your girlfriend in danger with an illegally modified vehicle. If she's lucky enough not to be involved in an accident she might still be sentenced for reckless driving.

Comment: Sorry guys, my question was more of a technical in nature but all of you are focusing on my girlfriend, who is by the way sporty, very familiar with high speed, rides a motorbike and pretty fast on the ski slopes. And just imagine, any time you descend from a hill you can easily accelerate over 45-50km/h with or without electric assistance. In my opinion 40km/h on the flat in tailwind is much safer.

Comment: @Challenger consider that depending on your location, your modded ebike may already be illegal on the road.  It might be categorised as an electric motorcycle with all the requirements that entails.

Answer (score 2):

You face two options:

1. upgrade to an e-bike with support up to 45 km/h;

2. downgrade your bike.

Regarding 1., the only difference I am aware of is the need of a very simple driving license permit and/or compulsory helmet. I hope the helmet is already part of your e-bike-set-up-for-your-girlfriend.

Regarding 2., what is your goal? who is training and who is enjoying time with the relevant other?
a very simple solution is to have a decent bicycle with rack and panniers, then load the panniers with rocks or metal blocks, allowing you to maximize the effort towards cardio/power output while reducing your speed.

You are a well trained cyclist, so you can decouple your body from your bike and analyze your training to achieve the same power output/cardio with a different speed. Increased air resistance that you will get from higher speed can be recreated with reverse wind shield or other contraptions, a part from increasing the weight of your bike.
To balance your training, you will be required to spend the same time and brain efforts you are now putting into understanding and tuning an e-bike to be used (illegally) on public roads.

But the failure in doing this properly is just you will be missing some training, instead of putting your girlfriend in serious trouble, physically or legally, in case of an accident with a tuned e-bike.

Comment: One easy way to make cycling harder is to attach a trailer with a kid of two sitting inside it. Good for the whole family.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov this setup may take a bit of time to be arranged, according to the OP current availability of kids at home :)

Comment: at least such an arrangement would more likely to be legal in most jurisdictions, and would also benefit the population of future avid cyclists!

Comment: 2.) is rather boring and demotivating.

Comment: @Michael how demotivating can be when then you pick up your racing bike and you feel you are flying like a rocket? even Hermann Maier the ski-champion was training by hauling 110-pound bags of cement and pushing wheelbarrows full of brick and stone (kind of, since it was his job at the time).

Comment: @EarlGrey: Most climbers, cyclists, runners etc. don’t train with weight strapped to their bodies. The idea comes up from time to time but apparently it sounds better in theory than it is in practice. If one wants to do strength training it’s better to do dedicated strength training exercises (with appropriate (high) weight and (low) number of repetitions).

Comment: @Michael OP goal is not to do strength training: the weights are not for strength training, just to allow him to go slower with the same cardio/cadence

Comment: Thanks for your comment but when we use the bike then we would like to see more from the world, explore a bigger area, enjoy the travelling at a decent speed therefore I don't want to be slower. We live in a rural area, no worry about trafic and by the way my girlfriend has already accompanied me with a motorbike once so she is familiar with the speed and the two wheels. :)

Comment: @Challenger then look for a tandem: there are awesome, high quality tandem manufactured out there :D ! Even a very good quality tandem, hand made with DI2 component and all the frills (without electric motor) should cost less than any of the top of the line road bikes.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this experience with my retail stock 2018 Bosch CX bike.  Peak assist in a climb definitely happens around a 90ish cadence.  Perhaps the 'tuning' method applied isn't handling this situation well?

A hub motor system may suit your needs better even though they feel less "natural" when assisting, since their ability to assist has nothing to do with what you're putting into the cranks.  They are also used almost exclusively by people who build (off-public-road only!) high speed e-bikes.

This chart is commonly shared around e-bike forums, it's a few years old so may not hold true for the latest models, and unfortunately I do not have a source for the original creator.  It does show though that Yamaha/Shimano would no be expected to be a magic fix.

[image]

Comment: The comment that hub motors "ability to assist has nothing to do with what you're putting into the cranks" only applies to some hub motor systems -- my e-cargo setup uses a torque/speed sensing bottom bracket and sets the motor torque as a multiplier on my crank power; the older BionX setup measured cassette torque and multiplied that. In the US at least, hub motors are also widely available for on-road usage, and off-road riders seem to favor bottom-bracket drives.

Comment: Yes of course, I meant as far as what one can do with software "tuning" if the gearing inside a mid-drive is too far out of the motor's power band when the crank is turning at 110 cadence then there's nothing you can do to change that from the controller.  With a hub drive as long as the wheel is spinning at a speed the hub is able to assist the controller can be tuned to add more power to that final wheel speed regardless of what's going on at the crank.

Comment: During climbing we have no issue! She can keep my tempo even in the tour mode! But climbing is always lower RPM and higher torque. 

Unfortunately the chart that you showed is totally useless. FIrst of all, the motor cannot support more than 250W, so even if the max power would be around 500W that means nothing. I am absolutely sure the motor could provide its full allowed power even at 90-100 RPM, but the algorithm is designed different.

Answer (score -1):

> We bought a Cannondale Kinneto 2013 for my girlfriend and I also mounted a tuning kit that removes the 25km/h limit.

I hope you aren't planning to use that illegal tuned bike on public roads. There is a reason why electric assist is limited to low speeds.

> Similarly on downhill parts I can easily reach 50km/h but according to her she hit a wall at 40-45km/h (of course this can come from the max supported cadence of the gen1 motor (105rpm)).

I have reached 70 km/h on downhills with no electric assist -- and I live in a non-hilly area. The way you do this is this:

- Select a drop bar bike
- Install narrow slick tires
- Pump the tires to a very high pressure
- When encountering a downhill, stop pedaling and coast when doing downhill; you'll initially at the very start of the downhill want to accelerate with a high gear but when acceleration is no longer useful, you stop it
- Use the most aerodynamic position possible

I don't think pedaling, with or without electric assist, is of any use. A person in fit condition can achieve greater powers than what the tiny electric motor can achieve, momentarily. Only in the long run does the motor win, until the battery is flat that is. However, pedaling at high RPM is inherently inefficient, and for this reason the electric assist motors connected to bottom bracket aren't optimized for high RPMs either -- because they don't need to be. It's only assist, not the primary power source. Besides, if pedaling downhill, the additional air currents from moving legs probably affect your air resistance, very possibly more than what extra power you get.

Put the largest chainring you can find, and use it with the smallest rear sprocket you can find. Then you can avoid ridiculously high RPMs. 250 watts is 250 watts, no matter what the RPM is.

In fact, I would argue that small differences in the max electric assist RPM are completely outshadowed by air resistance. At high speeds, the primary resisting force is air resistance. A drop bar bike with low handlebars, and having hands on the drops, and using a non-flopping jacket as opposed to one that starts flopping in the wind, achieves you far more than some modification to permit electric assist with 10 or 20 more revolutions per minute.

So, put a drop bars with the lowest comfortable height and high gearing on the bike. Use clothes optimal for cycling.

Comment: Well, of course the air resistance could be even lower but the current bike is already one of the best available in this regard. For me the downhill where I reach 50km/h is only -4-5% steep, so I still have to push the pedals. Of course on a very steep descent she could definitely reach 50km/h, but that is not under question.

Comment: If you are familiar with cycling then you know that 250W is a lot! especially for a woman with 55kg. I think my girlfriend can put out around 100W for a longer period (over an hour). There is no issue with ridiculously high RPMs, 90-95 is totally normal.